# Points not aligned on x-axis of ggplot 1-column facet wrap

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, facet-wrap, posixlt

Please kindly check and advice on how I can resolve the difference in the two plots generated by the following script:

```
time1 <- c(
  as.POSIXlt("2021-05-02 23:57:29"),
  as.POSIXlt("2021-05-02 23:58:29"),
  as.POSIXlt("2021-05-02 23:59:29"),
  as.POSIXlt("2021-05-03 11:06:00"),
  as.POSIXlt("2021-05-03 11:07:00"),
  as.POSIXlt("2021-05-03 11:08:00")
)
time2 <- c(
  as.POSIXlt("2021-05-02 23:59:29"),
  as.POSIXlt("2021-05-02 23:59:29"),
  as.POSIXlt("2021-05-02 23:59:29"),
  as.POSIXlt("2021-05-03 11:08:00"),
  as.POSIXlt("2021-05-03 11:08:00"),
  as.POSIXlt("2021-05-03 11:08:00")
)

grp <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C")
cnt <- c(29,1,30,31,2,33)

df1 <- data.frame(time1, grp, cnt)
df2 <- data.frame(time2, grp, cnt)

p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = time1, y = cnt, color = grp)) +
  geom_jitter(size = 1.0, show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~grp, ncol = 1, shrink = FALSE)

p2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = time2, y = cnt, color = grp)) +
  geom_jitter(size = 1.0, show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~grp, ncol = 1, shrink = FALSE)
```

Plot p1 shows the points as aligned as per their time1 values. In plot p2 the points are not aligned.

[image: Plot p1]

[image: Plot p2]

Comment: It will probably be the geom_jitter doing different things when the data are closely spaced or identical. So in P1 it jitters them within the minute separating the values, whereas in P2 it jitters between the two unique values 11 hours apart. You might need to apply the jitter manually and then use `geom_point`

Comment: The comment from @RichardTelford was the earliest comment/answer to my query, and is also spot on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `?geom_jitter`, you will see that there would be a random variation to the point location:

> The jitter geom is a convenient shortcut for geom_point(position =
> "jitter"). It adds a small amount of random variation to the location
> of each point, and is a useful way of handling overplotting caused by
> discreteness in smaller datasets.

To have deterministic layout, you should use `geom_point`, which gives you
[image]